# How to inspect a variable on a JSP page?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp

I have a set of working pages and want to inspect variables at a breakpoint on a JSP page. Unfortunately, the context menu for the variable doesn't show the normal Inspect/Watch options as it does when in a Java file. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try out.print()?

Comment: That's always an option.  I ran into this problem when JSP was first rolled out.  My work around was to put a thin cover over the functionality I wanted and set a break point in a static helper class.  I don't like fighting the tool that is supposed to help me.

Comment: So I'm still stuck here. Eclipse won't display the contents of a variable at a JSP break point.  I can inspect the contents if I walk into a function its passed to, but can't inspect within the page.  At the break point the variable type is displayed if I hover over it but a context menu without inspection options is displayed if I right click the variable.

Comment: Try setting the breakpoint just after the variable and inspect it there. It may be a case that it will not show these options if it is empty which it may be at that point.

Comment: Gave that a go.  No luck.  When I hover all it shows me is the class of the variable.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here is a solution worked for me:

In Eclipse open the Display tab  view (Window -> Show View -> Display)
In the Display tab write the variable or expression you want to inspect.
Select it and do a right click and you'll have the a menu with the option inspect (or you can do a Ctrl + Shift + I), it will show you the value of the variable.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks ! just a clarification, after entering the variable in the display panel, *select it* (so it is highlighted) and then click the magnifying glass on the top right of the display panel.

Comment: This works if I add the variable to the Variables tab of the Display view.  Its a work around.  Thanks for the help.  Unfortunately, I am not getting notifications from SO and didn't see your response until now.  BTW.  The same problem exits in Luna.  Also when I Ctrl + Shit + I it inserts a tab rather than inspecting the JSP page variable.

Comment: One more success.  With Luna hitting a break point in a JSP page and having the Variables tab visible in the Display view shows all JSP variables.  A huge win and time saver.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 6):

Struggled with the same problem and then looked at the variables View(Window) in Eclipse. All variables are there with their names and values.

But watch/inspect entries are indeed missing in right click menu.

BTW, I'm using Eclipse Kepler.

Comment: Watch/inspect entries are missing in right click menu of Luna also