# Not able to inspect JSP Varaibles in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, variables, inspect

I'm having problems inspecting the contents of variables on a JSP page using Eclipse Kepler.  I can pause over them and see the variable type in the tool tip but not the contents.  I can not inspect the variable.  Also when an exception is thrown the JSP source is not located when I click the exception source link in the console.  Any ideas?  Is there a compiler setting I need to change?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12980979/how-to-inspect-a-variable-on-a-jsp-page